# c# - How to filter datagridview between dates column that contain words and date?

Tags: c#, date, datagridview, filter, between

I have column called DateColumn which stores creation date like this:

```
created at 2017-01-20
created at 2017-01-21
created at 2017-01-22
created at 2017-01-23
created at 2017-01-24
```

How can I get only the dates between 20 and 24 while the column also contains "created at" string?

I tried this and it worked but only on columns with just the date in theme no words:

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "DateColumn  >= '" + minDate + "' AND DateColumn <= '" + maxDate + "'";
```

Comment: Does your DataTable come from Database?

Comment: Your DateColumn type is varchar and minDate type is Datetime?

Comment: There is not straight comparison you can between DateTime value and varchar column. You need to figure out a way to extract date from the column and then compare with the DateTime Value.

Comment: minDate and maxDate are from datetimepicker and yes DateColumn type is varchar in my mysql database.

Comment: I suggest that you extract content of that column into new column, in your SQL query that fetches data. That way you can have DateTime column which can be filtered or ordered by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that "created at" is inside your column. Now you have to find workaround for this. You better should consider if it's necessary that "created at" is there. If you select these values (inside your DataTable) from a Database you could substring this in your select.

For example (Oracle-Style):

```
SELECT someValue1, someValue2, TO_DATE(SUBSTR(DateColumn, 10, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD') DateColumn
FROM something
```

If you definitive need this text what probably isn't the case you should make a new column into your DataTable which only consists of the date. You can filter this column then:

```
DataTable yourTable = new DataTable();
//Fill with strange strings like 'created at 2017-01-01'
yourTable.Columns.Add("RealDate");

foreach (DataRow row in yourTable.Rows)
{
   //Instead of substr you can also use regex if you prefer
   row["RealDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(Substring(row["DateColumn"], 10, 10));
}
```

After both of my solutions you can easily filter the new row for DateTime as you mentioned in your question.